# Get values from onclick attribute using python bs4

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am unable to parse through the onclick attribute to get only selected values. Here is the onclick attribute

```
onclick="try{appendPropertyPosition(this,'B10331465','9941951739','','Dealer','Murugan.N');jsb9onUnloadTracking();jsevt.stopBubble(event);}catch(e){};"
```

How do I get only selected values from this onclick attribute such as (phonenumber , '', 'Dealer','Name'). Here is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
url="http://www.99acres.com/property-in-velachery-chennai-south-ffid?"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
properties = soup.findAll('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
for eachproperty in properties:
 print "http:/"+ eachproperty['href']+",", eachproperty.string, eachproperty['onclick']
```

**UPDATE**

I want to get only one phone number, though there are many, from the above mentioned `onclick` attribute.

for example, right now I am getting

```
Y10765227, 9884877926, 9283183326,, Dealer, Rgmuthu
L10038779, 9551154555, ,, ,
R10831945, 9150000747, 9282109134, 9043728565, ,, ,
B10750123, 9952946340, , Dealer, Bala
R10763559, 9841280752, 9884797013, , Dealer, Senthil
```

This I am getting by using the following code

```
re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", (a['onclick'] if a else ''))
```

I am trying to modify in such a way that only one phone number is retrieved and the rest should vanish. It should look like this

```
    Y10765227, 9884877926, Dealer, Rgmuthu
    L10038779, 9551154555
    R10831945, 9150000747
    B10750123, 9952946340, Dealer, Bala
    R10763559, 9841280752, Dealer, Senthil
```

I am trying to use

```
re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", (re.sub(r'([^,]+,[^,]+,)(.*?)([A-Za-z].*)', r'\1\0',a['onclick']) if a else ''))
```

But this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for getting the data out of `onclick`:

```
properties = soup.findAll('a', title=re.compile('Bedroom'))
for eachproperty in properties:
    print re.findall("'([a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*)'", eachproperty['onclick'])
```

prints:

```
['Y10765227', '9884877926, 9283183326', '', 'Dealer', 'Rgmuthu']
['L10038779', '9551154555', ',', ',']
['R10831945', '9150000747, 9282109134, 9043728565', ',', ',']
['B10750123', '9952946340', '', 'Dealer', 'Bala']
['R10763559', '9841280752, 9884797013', '', 'Dealer', 'Senthil']
...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. It worked. But I do not want the first value ie : 'Y10765227'. Is there any way to rip it off?

Comment: Just take `[1:]` slice from findall.